# Paypal IPN sending data through GET instead of POST even though rm value is 2

Tags: post, paypal, notifications, paypal-ipn

I've coded the paypal IPN exactly the way it should be coded, including the confirmation page. Everything works perfectly in the sandbox, but in the real environment paypal keeps sending the data through GET instead of post, even after keeping the rm value =2. So I've read some articles and changed auto return on. Still it returns via GET, then again I changed auto return to off, still it returns via GET...

I need the information through POST, including the variables I've passed...Somebody please help me here....

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make sure that you do not have auto return with PDT enabled in your account.  This will cause the post to be a GET.  If you are passing over the return URL in your code and setting the variable "rm" to "2", it should be getting returned as a post.  If, this is still not working, can you provide your button code that you are using so that I can take a look at the code and the account.

I just tested this with my account and it is working correctly.

Comment: Thank you for the post, I'm sorry the first time I tested, I didnt actually turn the PDT off, so got the information through GET. I've sorted it now... Paypal really needs to work on its documentation...

Answer (score 0):

Are you hosted with shared hosting on GoDaddy?  Your host may not allow POST requests from 3rd party servers?

Comment: Its on blue host actually, but why does it send through GET? what should i do now?

Comment: And one more thing it is an addon domain, so i linked to the main domain since addon domain is not secure so i gave a complete link like https://secure.bluehost.com/~username/a/pay/ipn.php.

Comment: But that worked perfectly with sandbox(using same address). It sent through post and was working perfectly, once I changed the sandbox id to real id problem began...